# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

```
class Coffee:
    def __init__(self):
        self._price=4.0

    def price(self):
        return self._price


    def __str__(self):
        return "Coffee with price "+ str(self._price)


class CoffeeWithMilk:
    def __init__(self, coffee):
        self.price+=coffee.price+0.5

    def price(self):
        return self.price


coffee=Coffee()

x=CoffeeWithMilk(coffee)
coffeeWithMilk=CoffeeWithMilk(x)
print(coffeeWithMilk)
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing an in place addition? You can also see that `price` is a method

Comment: self.price=coffee.price()+0.5

Answer (score 2):

`coffee.price` is a *method*, so `coffee.price + 0.5` gives you that error.

If you wanted to get the result of that method instead, *call* the method:

```
self._price = coffee.price() + 0.5
```

Note, I replaced `+=` with `=` here, you are setting a new attribute after all. I also *renamed* the attribute, because otherwise your `CoffeeWithMilk.price` method will get really confused too, causing a *second* error that looks a lot the same, as `self.price` is still a method too. This necessitates fixing the `def price(self)` method to:

```
def price(self):
    return self._price
```

So the completed code looks like this:

```
class Coffee:
    def __init__(self):
        self._price = 4.0

    def price(self):
        return self._price

    def __str__(self):
        return "Coffee with price " + str(self._price)


class CoffeeWithMilk:
    def __init__(self, coffee):
        self._price = coffee.price() + 0.5

    def price(self):
        return self._price
```

You can avoid re-defining the `price` method altogether by using *class inheritance*; make `CoffeeWithMilk` a specialised version of `Coffee`:

```
class Coffee:
    name = 'Coffee'

    def __init__(self):
        self._price = 4.0

    def price(self):
        return self._price

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} with price {}".format(self.name, self._price)


class CoffeeWithMilk(Coffee):
    name = 'Coffee with milk'

    def __init__(self, coffee):
        self._price = coffee.price() + 0.5
```

You get the `__str__` implementation along too, so your final `print(coffeeWithMilk)` will output something a little more interesting.

You could also make `Coffee.price` a [*property*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property); properties are methods that are automatically called for you each time you access the attribute:

```
class Coffee:
    name = 'Coffee'

    def __init__(self):
        self._price = 4.0

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} with price {}".format(self.name, self._price)


class CoffeeWithMilk(Coffee):
    name = 'Coffee with milk'

    def __init__(self, coffee):
        self._price = coffee.price + 0.5
```

In this case, I'd not use either a method or a property however. There is no need to make `_price` hidden here. Just replace it with a direct attribute:

```
class Coffee:
    name = 'Coffee'

    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 4.0

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} with price {}".format(self.name, self.price)


class CoffeeWithMilk(Coffee):
    name = 'Coffee with milk'

    def __init__(self, coffee):
        self.price = coffee.price + 0.5
```

That's because neither the method nor the property do anything more than pass along the `_price` attribute. You may as well just directly access it.

Last but not least, you create a `CoffeeWithMilk` instance from a `Coffee` instance, then *another* `CoffeeWithMilk` instance from the first `CoffeeWithMilk` instance, so your final instance has added 0.5 to 4 *twice*:

```
>>> coffee = Coffee()
>>> x = CoffeeWithMilk(coffee)  # first instance, from coffee
>>> print(x)
Coffee with milk with price 4.5
>>> coffeeWithMilk = CoffeeWithMilk(x)  # second instance, from x
>>> print(coffeeWithMilk)
Coffee with milk with price 5.0
```